# Transition between screens on Android

Tags: android, emulation, back-button

My application has screens and there is only one activity. My main activity is like: I have methods for calling the screen, I didn't use activity (I read somewhere that usage is more complicated.) So I used methods, but there is one problem.

When I open the activity the loginScreen is coming **OK**

When I click the loginBtn the listScreen is coming **OK**

But, when I click the back button in listScreen for coming back to loginScreen, the app is closing and open the home screen of emulator.

Normally;

**loginScreen --> loginBtn --> listScreen --> listBtn --> writeScreen**

What I want is coming back on this path with "back" button on emulator. I don't want to do that with override the back button because with this way I can only set one thing into the method.

```
public class EmailActivity extends Activity 
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        loginScreen();
    }

public void loginScreen() 
{
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
                Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                listScreen();
            }

        });
}

public void listScreen()
{
            this.setContentView(R.layout.list);
                Button listBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList);

        listBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                setContentView(R.layout.writeScreen);
            }

        });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you must write an Activity for each screen you use in the app... you are just calling methods, and in memory you have just one Activity so, the back button pop the Activity and return to the home...
Read this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

If you wanna call another screen(Activity)m you create an instance of a Intent, which tells the system "hey!, call the stuff i'm passing here", for example, you have two activities, called, A1 and A2, if you wanna call A2 from A1, you must do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A1.this,A2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

It will push A2 over A1, so when you press back, you will get A1

Comment: But there is too much thing that methods are share. Am I have to do this in this way? Or is there any way for only methods

Comment: Yes, the activity represent a different screen, if you wanna share data btw activities you must put data in the intent like intent.putExtra("myDataKey",myData); or using a Context

Comment: OK I understand thank you so much. But just to clarify the method and activity situation. For a good and true working application the activity usage between screens is the best way for an application? I mean the method usage between screens means sliding over application?

Comment: Yes, the Android Framework is maded to be used that way, a screen -> an Activity, so the flow of the app is calling Activities from another ones
Accept the answer if i helped you!

Answer (score 1):

For coming back to the previous screen you will need to use different activities. Now you have just one activity and when you press back button, your app closes that activity and consequently your entire application closes.

If you still want to do it this way, you can override the hardware back button to call the above described methods rather than closing the app.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, the only way to achieve what you have asked is to override the back button.  The back button by default closes the current activity and returns to the previous one.  In your case, you only have one activity so your app closes.  Overriding the back button is easy and you would still be able to control your "views".

You could track where you are with a couple of class level fields (private variables) in your activity class, e.g.

```
private int currentView;
private int lastView;
private static enum Views {LoginScreen, ListScreen}

...
...

public void loginScreen() 
{

    lastView = currentView;
    currentView = Views.LoginScreen;

    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
            listScreen();
        }

    });
}

public void listScreen()
{

    lastView = currentView;
    currentView = Views.ListScreen;

    this.setContentView(R.layout.list);
    Button listBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList);

    listBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
            setContentView(R.layout.writeScreen);
        }

    });

}
```

However, you really are doing this the wrong way, especially if you want to learn how to write Android apps and perhaps publish some on the app stores.

Activities are more complicated but for good reason and once you've learned the basics, you'll never look back.  I really recommend that you create an activity for each of your screens.  You have to do a little bit more work but, you will end up with MORE control over how your apps behaves and better, more maintainable code.
[Start here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

If you're targeting HC and above, you might also want to look at Fragments:

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Go for it.  You won't be sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will follow your recommends